# Algorithm for removing entries from an array, by removing "middlest" items?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Given a list of items of length `n`, where a maximum number of wanted items is `m`, and `m < n`, and in which the items in the list which are most valuable / useful are those that are furthest from any other item. How can I remove items from the list to reduce the size of the list to `m`.

- e.g., for `[ a, b, c, d, e ]` with an `m == 2`, we would get `[ a, e]`
- e.g., for `[ a, b, c, d, e ]` with an `m == 3`, we would get `[ a, c, e ]`
- e.g., for `[ a, b, c, d, e ]` with an `m == 4`, we would get `[ a, b, c, e ]` or `[ a, c, d, e ]`. (Either answer would be valid; but only one should be returned, and preferably it would be deterministically returned.)

Note: I am generalizing a real problem, which is selecting representative frames from a video. The code will be written in python.

Comment: First, does `[ a, b, c, d, e ]` mean `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`, or something different? And what does "furthest" mean? Do you have some kind of distance function in mind, like `abs(ord(x) - ord(y))`? If so, are the values guaranteed to be in sorted order? And can you give us some examples of what output you want for values that aren't just linearly increasing? Or do you just minimizing the distances between _indexes_, not _values_ of the skips? Or…?

Answer (score 2):

Step through the list with steps of about size `(n-1)/(m-1)`, where "about" is there because we can't land on a non-integer.

```
def representatives(l, m):
    num, den = len(l)-1, m-1
    return [l[i * num // den] for i in range(m)]
```

Here, element `i` of the result is taken from element `i*(n-1)//(m-1)` of the input, where `//` is floor division.

Answer (score 2):

For a collection `c`:

```
sparse_list = c[::len(c)//(m-1)]
```

This returns a list with a step size of `len(c)//(m-1)` (note integer division).

e.g.:

```
c = list(range(50))
m = 5
c[::len(c)//(m-1)] # [0, 12, 24, 36, 48]
```

It's not quite perfect because it goes for exact spacing, but it's quick and easy (and performant).

Comment: Wow! I've never seen the `::` syntax before! cooool